# Write a file in a docker container and read from another container

Tags: docker, selenium, docker-compose, devops

I have a project like this structure:

```
app
    - selenium
        - downloads
.env
docker-compose.yml
```

**`docker-compose.yml`** has 2 services: `myApp` and `selenium`. And this volumes set for my services:

**`myApp`:**

```yaml
volumes:
  - ./app:/home/app
```

**`selenium`:**

```yaml
volumes:
  - ./app/selenium/downloads:/home/seluser/Downloads
```

When I run `docker compose up` in this directory, My application and selenium run up and I can develop my application. sometimes I need the `selenium` container for getting some content around the web.

When `selenium container` downloads a file, this file is stored in the `./app/selenium/downloads` and I can `read` this file from the `myApp container`.

**Problem**

When I changed the selenium default download directory to `/home/seluser/Downloads/aaa/bbb`, this directory can access by the `selenium` container with `/home/app/selenium/downloads/aaa/bbb`, But I can't access `aaa` directory in the `myApp` container.

I can Change the permission of the `aaa` directory with the `root` user in the `myApp` container and solve this problem, But the default download directory can be changed for every downloaded file.

What's the solution to this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess that you are getting troubles because your main processes of your 2 containers are running with different user. There is an easy way is to modify your Dockerfile and set the same user id (UID) for these both users. So the file/directory generated by a container can be accessed properly by the user of the other container.

An example `Dockerfile` to create a user with specified UID

```
ARG UNAME=testuser
ARG UID=1000
ARG GID=1000
RUN groupadd -g $GID -o $UNAME
RUN useradd -m -u $UID -g $GID -o -s /bin/bash $UNAME
```

There is another way using `umask` to assign proper permission to file/directory generated in your selenium container (to grant READ access to all users). But I think it's more complicated and make take your time to know which umask is suitable for you https://phoenixnap.com/kb/what-is-umask

Comment: This solution worked for me and I currently can access the target directory, But I can't access to the file in the target directory.

Comment: Solved. Thank you. My app was written in python. So in python, I changed the file permission with this code `os.chmod(file, 0o777)` and then read the file.